# WebClient.OpenReadAsync(url) throws OutOfMemory when downloading large file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, out-of-memory, webclient

I am using `WebClient` to download files from `url`, the following code works fine for small file sizes but throws `OutOfMemoryException` when downloading video files > 100MB.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.OpenReadCompleted += (send, args) => Save(fileName, albumName, args.Result, uri);
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += webClient_DownloadAlbumsProgressChanged;
webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri);
```

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.

Please Help me